# sending keystrokes as output using a raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm creating a game in Godot and have to create a remote for the game, I decided on using Raspberry Pi's but I'm running into an issue where I can't output anything from the Pi to the game through a USB. Is there another approach I can try or anything I need to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Alternate approaches would be `Network`, `Bluetooth` and `Serial` Communication.